# jQuery loop select ID dynamic from inputs

Tags: jquery, loops, laravel-livewire

I have a problem with select2 in loop. I need to get the IDs of the dynamic inputs and start the select2 of each one.

Is there any simple way to do this? Because the way I'm using it, my code would be static and that would cause several problems.

Here is an example of how I'm doing it. I'm using Laravel with livewire, and I need this structure for the livewire to communicate with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.initSelectCompanyDrop = () => {
    $('#nome0').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome1').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome2').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome3').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome4').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome5').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome6').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome7').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome8').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome9').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
    $('#nome10').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
      allowClear: true
    });
  }
  
  initSelectCompanyDrop();

  window.livewire.on('select2', () => {
    initSelectCompanyDrop();
  });
  
  $(document).on('change', '#nome0', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.0', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome1', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.1', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome2', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.2', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome3', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.3', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome4', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.4', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome5', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.5', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome6', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.6', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome7', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.7', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome8', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.8', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome9', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.9', e.target.value);
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#nome10', function(e) {
    @this.set('nome.10', e.target.value);
  });
});

document.addEventListener("livewire:load", function(event) {
  window.livewire.hook('afterDomUpdate', () => {
    $('#nome0, #nome1, #nome2, #nome3, #nome4, #nome5, #nome6, #nome7, #nome8, #nome9, #nome10').select2({
      placeholder: 'Selecione...',
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is what classes are for. You could also use a partial attribute selector since the IDs have a pattern. What do you prefer?

Comment: how i can do that? I don't really like scripts, that's why I always run away from these classes haha

Comment: Even the [Select2 docs](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) use classes.

Comment: Oh yes of course!
but when I select in onchange, I cant use the classes as I need to select the specific field so...this would solve 50% of my problem :/

Comment: See also `$(this)`.